# Why does this error keep messing up the XE2 IDE Toolbars?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-7, ide, delphi-xe2

**Screen Shot**

[image]

The following source code was used to produce the error above. All you have to do is compile the program and make sure the IDE is still running (the error does NOT happen if the IDE is closed), click the button 12 to 15 times and the error will popup.

Once the error has occurred, switch back to the IDE, all the toolbars for the IDE have then disappeared.  You have to shut down the IDE and run again, for them to reappear.

**Source Code**

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.ShlObj, System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, System.StrUtils, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMainFrm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainFrm: TMainFrm;
  hDesktop: HWND;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetHandle(theHandle: HWND; NotUsed: NativeInt): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
  if (theHandle <> 0) then
  begin
    hDesktop := FindWindowEx(FindWindowEx(theHandle, 0, 'SHELLDLL_DefView',
      nil), 0, 'SysListView32', nil);
  end;
  Result := (hDesktop = 0);
end;

procedure TMainFrm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lpss: TShellState;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lpss, SizeOf(lpss));
  try
    SHGetSetSettings(lpss, SSF_HIDEICONS, False);
  finally
    Button1.Caption := IfThen(lpss.fHideIcons, 'Show Icons', 'Hide Icons');
  end;
  EnumWindows(@GetHandle, 0);
  Button1.Enabled := (hDesktop <> 0);
end;

procedure TMainFrm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  nCmdShow: array [Boolean] of NativeInt = (SW_HIDE, SW_SHOW);
var
  lpss: TShellState;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lpss, SizeOf(lpss));
  try
    SHGetSetSettings(lpss, SSF_HIDEICONS, False);
    ShowWindow(hDesktop, nCmdShow[lpss.fHideIcons]);

    lpss.fHideIcons := (not BOOL(lpss.fHideIcons));
    Button1.Caption := IfThen(lpss.fHideIcons, 'Show Icons', 'Hide Icons');
  finally
    SHGetSetSettings(lpss, SSF_HIDEICONS, True);
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Application Screen Shot**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The IDE toolbars no longer disappear, and the error doesn't appear anymore, thanks to TOndrej for the information about turning off the "Profiler toolbar".  Now I get a very annoying flicker that sometimes takes 10 to 15 seconds to return back to normal.

Comment: I suggest you try the Delphi XE, if you can, it looks more stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have AQTime installed? The problem seems to disappear if you simply hide the Profiler toolbar.

Comment: I guess it won't be related to AQTime. I don't have it but all toolbars on all windows (not only Delphi IDE) flickers when the icons are being shown or hidden on my machine. However I didn't get the *A call to an OS function failed* error.

Comment: @TLama flicker is unrelated, the error probably is; reproducible every time when the Profiler toolbar is shown, couldn't reproduce when hidden.

Comment: I didn't expected the flickering. And you got my +1 because it just confirms your theory since I don't have AQTime installed ;-)

Comment: @TLama Thanks :-) The flickering can be explained by `TApplication.CheckIniChange` -> `TScreen.IconFontChanged` which broadcasts `CM_SYSFONTCHANGED` to all IDE forms which propagates to children recursively. The toolbars handle this message by recreating their windows and that causes the flicker.

Comment: @TOndrej, The problem really doesn't go away when you close the Profiler toolbar, it just stops the "A call to an OS function failed" error from popping up. The flicker and very sluggish IDE behavior is unacceptable.

Comment: @eyeClaxton Funny because you never mentioned flicker as a problem in the original question. I thought the problem was the error and the subsequent instability of the IDE - which does seem to be caused by AQTime. If you want to get rid of the flicker - which is another problem - perhaps an acceptable solution to you would be to simply turn off [UpdateMetricSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.UpdateMetricSettings) from a design package.

Comment: @TOndre, I never mentioned the flicker because that's not what the toolbars were doing, mine just disappeared until I restarted the IDE.

Comment: @eye > *"The flicker and very sluggish IDE behavior is unacceptable"* - You would perhaps want to file a QC report then. You don't have to supply any code to duplicate, just tell them to switch themes while the IDE is open.